# Is there any way to fix incorrect file size?

Tags: linux, windows, filesystems, filesystem-corruption

I have two files that both the Windows operating system and Linux report as >700GB, when in fact my disk size is only 500GB, making it impossible for me to move it somewhere else. They were backed up from another machine which I no longer have access to, and I'm loathed to just delete it.

What are some possible causes of this, and is there anything I could do to fix it (or further identify the issue)?

Comment: I hate to ask a silly question.. but did you run chkdsk?

Comment: Yeah, no error were found